# how to reset the angle property of RotateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, angle

I have a canvas include some element to show an robot arm. This arm can stretch out and draw back by animation.

Now I need initialize the arm and keep collapsed status in some case(not by animation). So I need reset the angle property of RotateTransform.

```
 <Canvas x:Name="RobotArm_Left" Width="60" Height="10" RenderTransformOrigin="0.9167,0.5" Canvas.Top="62.5" Canvas.Left="12.5">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>                                   
            <RotateTransform x:Name="Rotate_RobotArm_Left" />                                    
        </TransformGroup>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

I use two ways to set the angle:

```
((RotateTransform)page.FindName("Rotate_RobotArm_Left")).Angle=0; //0 is the init value
((RotateTransform)page.FindName("Rotate_RobotArm_Left")).SetValue(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, 0.0);
```

they all don't work.

when I watch the value of ((RotateTransform)page.FindName("Rotate_RobotArm_Left")).Angle, it's -55.

Is there one way to set the property?

otherwise, before running animation, the angle property can be changed.But after animation,it cannot be changed.

thanks.

Comment: I find I can use this way to reset :((RotateTransform)page.FindName("Rotate_RobotArm_Left")).SetCurrentValue(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, 0.0);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An animated value takes precedence over a locally set value. Either stop your animation (in which case the value will revert back to its unanimated value) or animate it to the desired value. See [dependency property precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) for more info.

Using `SetCurrentValue` is a bit of a hack in this case because you're substituting the value yielded by the animation, not removing the animation as a value source altogether. In other words, the animation is still active, you've just changed the value it reports.

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx) should also be of interest.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Because run animation need take some time, but the initial should be finish right away, so I use SetCurrentValue function.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach might be useful:

Do not animate the rotation, instead animate a property of an object and bind the rotation angle to it. This will allow you control of the animations and free you from knowing/finding elements in the XAML.

Comment: This is a good idea, but need do more work on interpolating value of key frame.

Comment: @BruceWu - you can always write your own Animation class